# JavaScript working in IE8 and 9 but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I have this javascript to see if the drop-down is selected. If not an error message is displayed. The problem is that the code works in **IE9** and **8**, but not in **Chrome**.

The simple solution to this is to add the "**required**" attribute to the tag, but I want to know the reason that code isn't working.

```
<form name="form1" action="insert.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<table name="table1">
     <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="fruits">
                <option selected disabled>Please Select</option>
                <option value="banana>banana</option>
                <option value="apple>apple</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm()
    {
    var x=document.forms["form1"]["fruits"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="")
      {
      alert("Please Select Fruit");
      return false;
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How about putting an id on your select and use `document.getElementById()` rather than `document.forms["form1"]["fruits"]` to get the DOM object?

Comment: use document.getElementsByName("fruits")[0];

Comment: @jfriend00 tried with var ' x=document.getElementById("fruits").value; ' still doesn't work.

Comment: You have to add `id="fruits"` to the `<select>`.  `document.getElementById()` works with `id` values only, not name values.

Comment: @Isuru http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/3BTdk/8/

Comment: @Isuru then how you tried when it was not working

Comment: @Rex the problem with the onclick event was that after the alert is displayed, the content still got submitted, but removing the onlick event and adding value="" to "Please Select" option your code worked.
I voted the below answer as correct because that too worked!

Thanks for the help Rex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please review this code,`required` is the html5 attribute and by default check for `empty` values

```
<form name="form1" action="insert.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
    <table name="table1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="fruits">
                    <option value=" "  disabled>Please Select</option>
                    <option value="banana">banana</option>
                    <option value="apple">apple</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script>
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.forms["form1"]["fruits"].value;

        if (x == null || x == " ") {
            alert("Please Select Fruit");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/2zgGM/